# Proof that the Lie Algebra of Endomorphism of finite dimensional V is isomorphic to Lie algebra of n by n matrices.

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

I am starting a study of Lie Algebras and the text I am working out of simply states the following. I have been trying to come up with a proof but I am currently at a loss.

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$. We denote $L(End(V))$ as $gl(V)$. gl(V) is isomorphic to $gl(n)=L(M_n(k))$ of $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $k$.

The context here is that for any associative algebra $A$ we can define a lie bracket as $[a,b]=ab-ba$ for all $a,b\in A$. This give $A$ a Lie structure and we denote the Lie algebra as $L(A)$. Also $k$ is just some base field usually thought of as $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: The context is, that even for some classes of **non**-associative algebras, $[a,b]=ab-ba$ is a Lie bracket.

Comment: If you can get access, Jacobson's *Lie algebras* has a very clear description of this.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B$ be a basis of $V$. For each $f\in\operatorname{End}V$, let $M_f=[f]_B^B$. Then$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathfrak{gl}(V)&\longrightarrow&\mathfrak{gl}(n,k)\\f&\mapsto&M_f\end{array}$$is a Lie algebra isomorphism.

Comment: I'm not clear on your notation. What does M_f=?

Comment: It's the matrix of $f$ with respect to the basis $B$.

Comment: Okay I think I understand. Please correct me if I am wrong. Each f is an endomorphism which in turn is a linear transformation from V to V. We also know that any linear transformation can be represented by a matrix multiplication. So we are mapping each linear transformation to its corresponding matrix. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Not at all. That's it.